# Until + subjunctive

Tags: grammar, subjunctive-mood

Help, please. I've been pondering on this sentece for half an hour:

**I was determined to continue until the truth was discovered**

Leave wordiness aside, does this convey the same meaning as "I was determined to find the truth"? I feel a subjunctive form is needed after *until* (until the truth were discovered) so as to avoid ambiguity, but the use of subjunctive following *until* does not seem very common today. Sorry, I'm puzzled.

To those users who have kindly rated this question as off-topic because "it can be answered using commonly-available references," could you please provide one that accounts for the tense to be used after "until" to avoid ambiguity?

Comment: Until the car was washed. Until the game was over. Until peace was established. It is not subjunctive. It's a passive use of the verb. (I wonder why you think it is subjunctive. I don't understand where these ideas comes from.)

Comment: @Lambie I see the following ambiguity if the indicative tense is used:

I was determined to continue until the truth was discovered (I was determined to continue but sth happened that stopped me from continuing)

Comment: Does: *I am determined to continue until the truth is discovered* mean, or can it mean, that something happens that stops me from continuing? If something happens that stops me from continuing, it is not something marked by grammar but by the fact that my determination wasn't strong enough.

Comment: @user9825893y50932 Sure it does if you look closely at *until + past tense*. "I was very happy until I heard the news:" I was happy until the news stopped me from being so. Not understanding a question should not be a reason for downvoting it.

Comment: Ambiguity is rarely a problem in reality. 'I was determined to continue until the truth was discovered' would be pragmatically read as 'I was determined to continue until the truth should be discovered', just like 'This lamb is wicked' would only cause problems for someone looking for them.  In any case, I think the other sense is suspect here; I'd use 'I continued determinedly until the truth was discovered.'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The subjunctive form would be "I was determined to continue until the truth should be discovered" which is grammatically correct, but rather too formal for normal use. "Until the truth was discovered" is a perfectly normal form nowadays.